# BMI calculator always return 0. (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

i was just writing this very simple script to calculate bmi in kg and cm.
But it always prints 0. Any ideas why?

code:

```
weight = int(raw_input("Weight in kg: "))
length = int(raw_input("Length in cm: "))

def bmi():
    bmi = (weight) / (length * length)
    return bmi

print bmi()
```

Comment: Due to integer division in Python 2.x, `a / b == 0` for all `a < b` if both `a` and `b` are integers.

Comment: Um, you're using Py 2.7 and performing int division, so you'll always get an int. If you divide, say, 60 by 175*175, that's going to be less than 1, so it ends up zero.

Comment: add this at the start: `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast it to `float`. `/` will do integer division always.

That is

```
bmi = float(weight) / float(length * length)
```

It will print

```
Weight in kg: 10
Length in cm: 20
0.025
```

Or do

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: To improve on this, as floats are often imperfect ways to represent calculations such as BMI, consider using the `Decimal` module.